# Python 3D geometry: draw angles

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, geometry, angle

Is there any from to draw "the angle between 2 vectors in 3D" in python like this image:

http://intmstat.com/vectors/cosines.gif

,i.e., like this post: [Best way to plot an angle between two lines in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227100/best-way-to-plot-an-angle-between-two-lines-in-matplotlib) but in 3D.

Thank you very much!
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Matplotlib` can draw in 3D.

Comment: Thanks @furas, I have drawn some arrows in Matplotlib but I don't find about this semi-circular lines. After that, I have decided to do the main part with python and then modify with inkscape.