# Calculating angles between line segments (Python) with math.atan2

Tags: python, trigonometry, angle, atan2, cartesian-coordinates

I am working on a spatial analysis problem and part of this workflow is to calculate the angle between connected line segments.

Each line segment is composed of only two points, and each point has a pair of XY coordinates (Cartesian). Here is the image from GeoGebra. **I am always interested in getting a positive angle in 0 to 180 range**. However, I get all kind of angles depending on the order of vertices in input line segments.

[image]

The input data I work with is provided as tuples of coordinates. Depending on the vertex creation order, the last/end point for each line segment can be different. Here are some of the cases in Python code. The order of line segments in which I get them is random, but in a tuple of tuples, the first element is the start point and the second one is the end point. `DE` line segment, for instance, would have `((1,1.5),(2,2))` and the `(1,1.5)` is the start point because it has the first position in the tuple of coordinates.

I however need to make sure I will get the same angle between `DE,DF` and `ED,DF` and so forth.

```
vertexType = "same start point; order 1"
            #X, Y    X Y coords
lineA = ((1,1.5),(2,2)) #DE
lineB = ((1,1.5),(2.5,0.5)) #DF
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)
#flip lines order
vertexType = "same start point; order 2"
lineB = ((1,1.5),(2,2)) #DE
lineA = ((1,1.5),(2.5,0.5)) #DF
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)

vertexType = "same end point; order 1"
lineA = ((2,2),(1,1.5)) #ED
lineB = ((2.5,0.5),(1,1.5)) #FE
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)
#flip lines order
vertexType = "same end point; order 2"
lineB = ((2,2),(1,1.5)) #ED
lineA = ((2.5,0.5),(1,1.5)) #FE
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)

vertexType = "one line after another - down; order 1"
lineA = ((2,2),(1,1.5)) #ED
lineB = ((1,1.5),(2.5,0.5)) #DF
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)
#flip lines order
vertexType = "one line after another - down; order 2"
lineB = ((2,2),(1,1.5)) #ED
lineA = ((1,1.5),(2.5,0.5)) #DF
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)

vertexType = "one line after another - up; line order 1"
lineA = ((1,1.5),(2,2)) #DE
lineB = ((2.5,0.5),(1,1.5)) #FD
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)
#flip lines order
vertexType = "one line after another - up; line order 2"
lineB = ((1,1.5),(2,2)) #DE
lineA = ((2.5,0.5),(1,1.5)) #FD
calcAngle(lineA, lineB,vertexType)
```

I have written a tiny function that takes combinations of the lines as args and calculates the angle between them. I am using the `math.atan2` which seemed to be best suited for this.

```
def calcAngle(lineA,lineB,vertexType):
    line1Y1 = lineA[0][1]
    line1X1 = lineA[0][0]
    line1Y2 = lineA[1][1]
    line1X2 = lineA[1][0]

    line2Y1 = lineB[0][1]
    line2X1 = lineB[0][0]
    line2Y2 = lineB[1][1]
    line2X2 = lineB[1][0]

    #calculate angle between pairs of lines
    angle1 = math.atan2(line1Y1-line1Y2,line1X1-line1X2)
    angle2 = math.atan2(line2Y1-line2Y2,line2X1-line2X2)
    angleDegrees = (angle1-angle2) * 360 / (2*math.pi)
    print angleDegrees, vertexType
```

The output I get is:

```
> -299.744881297 same start point; order 1
> 299.744881297 same start point; order 2
> 60.2551187031 same end point; order 1
> -60.2551187031 same end point; order 2
> -119.744881297 one line after another - down; order 1
> 119.744881297 one line after another - down; order 2
> -119.744881297 one line after another - up; line order 1
> 119.744881297 one line after another - up; line order 2
```

As you can see, I am getting different values depending on the order of vertices in a line segment and line segments order. I have tried to post-process the angles by finding out what kind of relation the source line had and flipping the lines, editing the angle etc. I've ended with a dozen of such cases and at some point they start to overlap and I cannot any longer find out whether -119.744 should become 60.255 (acute angle) or be left as 119.744 (obtuse angle) etc.

**Is there any discrete way to process the output angle values I receive from `math.atan2` to get only a positive value in 0 to 180 range?** **If not, what kind of other approach should I take?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest way to get at this problem is using the dot-product.

Try this code (I've commented practically everything):

```
import math

def dot(vA, vB):
    return vA[0]*vB[0]+vA[1]*vB[1]

def ang(lineA, lineB):
    # Get nicer vector form
    vA = [(lineA[0][0]-lineA[1][0]), (lineA[0][1]-lineA[1][1])]
    vB = [(lineB[0][0]-lineB[1][0]), (lineB[0][1]-lineB[1][1])]
    # Get dot prod
    dot_prod = dot(vA, vB)
    # Get magnitudes
    magA = dot(vA, vA)**0.5
    magB = dot(vB, vB)**0.5
    # Get cosine value
    cos_ = dot_prod/magA/magB
    # Get angle in radians and then convert to degrees
    angle = math.acos(dot_prod/magB/magA)
    # Basically doing angle <- angle mod 360
    ang_deg = math.degrees(angle)%360
    
    if ang_deg-180>=0:
        # As in if statement
        return 360 - ang_deg
    else: 
        
        return ang_deg
```

Now try your variations of lineA and lineB and all should give the same answer.

Comment: The gist of the testing code and output is [here](https://gist.github.com/abhinavrk/2100332f7d7f4c127b8c)

Comment: thanks for the code snippet, great to start with. The problem with the code is that it never reports any obtuse angles (>90). Try yourself with the ``lineA = ((0.6,3.6),(1.6,3)) lineB = ((1.6,3),(2,3.6))``. It reports 87.27, but should be 92.73. What could be done to fix that?

Comment: I've edited my post. I believe I've fixed it to give obtuse angles as well. Take a look.

Comment: thanks for the update. I had to use my old code where I had to flip the direction of line segments so the vectors will have the same start point (otherwise you cannot calculate the angle between the way I want) and your code (before the edit). It works fine, thank you so much for the math work.

Comment: the line: `angle = math.acos(dot_prod/magB/magA)` might be changed to `angle = math.acos(cos_)`
How could the code be changed to produce angles between 0 and 360?

Comment: Tried every solution from here and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226038/calculating-angle-between-two-vectors-in-python), this was the fastest solution taking `0.00012512699686340056` seconds to process.

Comment: '%360' is redundant as the output of arccos (math.acos) is within the interval [0, pi] radians (or [0, 180] degrees). Hence you should never get an angle less than 0 or greater than 180 degrees. The if-else statement that follows is also redundant. You should also consider clipping the input to math.acos to -1 (min) and 1 (max).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank man.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative solution using the formula:

[image]

where 'm1' is the slope of line 1 and 'm2' the slope of line 2. If line 1 is defined by the points P1 = [x1, y1] and P2 = [x2, y2], then slope 'm' is:

[image]

By using the formulas above you can find the angle in degrees between two lines as follows:

```
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2): # Line slope given two points:
    return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

def angle(s1, s2): 
    return math.degrees(math.atan((s2-s1)/(1+(s2*s1))))

lineA = ((0.6, 3.6), (1.6, 3))
lineB = ((1.6, 3), (2, 3.6))

slope1 = slope(lineA[0][0], lineA[0][1], lineA[1][0], lineA[1][1])
slope2 = slope(lineB[0][0], lineB[0][1], lineB[1][0], lineB[1][1])

ang = angle(slope1, slope2)
print('Angle in degrees = ', ang)
```

Comment: The return result in `angle` should be wrapped with `abs()` to avoid negative angles

Answer (score 6):

Too much work. Take the absolute value of the arccosine of the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Dot_product) of the two vectors divided by each of the lengths of the lines.

Comment: you mean this? `angle = arccos[(xa * xb + ya * yb) / (√(xa2 + ya2) * √(xb2 + yb2))]`