# How to find between two lines using python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

What is the best way to find the angle between the Blue and Green lines in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07AWz.png)?

The Blue line is straight, but the Green line is slightly tilted.

Green line coordinates are `[(923, 286), (1495, 306)]`.
Blue line coordinates are `[(901, 259), (901, 197)]`.

Here is my code of to calculate the angle:

```
def find_angle(A, B):
    # Calculate the slope of line A
    slope_A = (A[1][1] - A[0][1]) / (A[1][0] - A[0][0])
    # Calculate the slope of line B
    slope_B = (B[1][1] - B[0][1]) / (B[1][0] - B[0][0])
    # Calculate the angle between the lines
    print(slope_A,slope_B)
    angle = math.atan2(slope_B, slope_A)
    # Convert the angle from radians to degrees
    print(angle)
    angle_degrees = angle * 180 / math.pi
    return angle_degrees
```

My calculation result is 90 or 89, but the Green line is a little bit tilted, so the angle should be 91 or 93.

Here's another [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYXph.png).

What is the problem with my code and how to improve that?

Comment: Your code raises a ZeroDivisionError (B is vertical, slope is infinite). You could use `acos( u.v )` , with `u` and `v` the direction vector of the two lines (there are already lots of such answers on SO).

Comment: You should also use numpy, which lets you write things like `u = p2-p1` and `dot(u,v)` which is a lot easier to read than `A[...][...]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating angles between line segments (Python) with math.atan2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260962/calculating-angles-between-line-segments-python-with-math-atan2)

Comment: No,When i find the problem that time. I will check that but not its not work