# How to plot two linear lines on a graph in python with radius 1 and center at origin and measure the angle difference?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, polar-coordinates

I have an issue that I can't seem to solve. I have already acquired data from another source and created 2 polynomials that are identical in shape but not in orientation, that is one is rotated x degrees compared to the other, and if you rotate the graph x degrees back they will match.
I have already taken the derivative of both of the graphs at a certain point.
I would like to graph these slopes onto a unit circle on a polar graph, and somehow find the angle difference between these two line segments of slope i and j that extend from the origin.
I'm fairly new to python so I so not know how to begin plotting these in polar or finding a way to determine the angle difference. I know that by hand, you can take the inverse tangent but that will only give you a range from +90 to -90. I would like my number to fall in the range from 0 to 360 for rotation.

Any help is appreciated. If this isn't enough info or if it isn't clear enough I can provide more.

Comment: Part of your answer will surely be the dot product of your two lines. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226038/calculating-angle-between-two-lines-in-python) are some fine words on this very subject.

Comment: Did you take a look through the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#pie_and_polar_charts)??

Comment: I think 360 degree is 2*np.pi, so your x axis ranges from 0 to 2*np.pi. You could use a polar chart. Provide your functions and what you have done so far.

Comment: The slopes of both functions are -0.41955220665252518 and 0.24426141395298115. I can plot them onto matplotlib but I need to plot them on a polar graph as radii and find the angle between them. That's the part I'm not sure about how to accomplish